# Can I use multiprocessing in python for training differents small models in the the 8 cores of my CPU and 1 process in the GPU?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gpu, cpu

I´m doing hyperparameter tunning for small MLP model. For now I paralelize 8 models in the 8 cores of my CPU. But my GPU is not being used, and I want to train an 9th model there. This is my code now:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
procesos = []
for n in range(8):
    proceso = Process(target=study.optimize, args=(objective, ))
    procesos.append(proceso)
for proceso in procesos:
    proceso.start()
    sleep(4)

for proceso in procesos:
    proceso.join()
```

Comment: This is not how it works. multiprocessing library only allows you to parallelize tasks between CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

CPUs and GPUs are completely different.

GPU requires OpenCL/Cuda programming, which are completely different constructs. Python's multiprocessing uses only CPUs.

As for your question, no. You cannot use multiprocessing to simply offload computational effort to a GPU.